# Laravel: how to use validator for single elements?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I'm trying to make validation of `$id` and `$offer_id` inside my function:

```
public function getMessagesForOffer($id, $offer_id)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'id' => 'required|numeric',
        'offer_id' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response([
            'status' => 'error',
            'error' => 'invalid.credentials',
            'message' => 'Invalid credentials'
        ], 400);
    }    
 }
```

This is throwing an error: `"message": "Undefined variable: request",`

And I see that it's incorrect coded, how can I correct it to work with single elements when there is no request inside my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request->all()` would just return array, so you can also use array here, so instead of `$request->all()` you can use:

```
['id' => $id, 'offer_id' => $offer_id]
```

or shorter:

```
compact('id', 'offer_id')
```

Comment: dzięki, dzięki!